# Software to log employee activities and restict access in remote locations

Tags: windows, networking, network-monitor, monitoring, google-apps

We are trying to log all the employee work data on a daily basis. But the problem is we have branches at remote locations (non profit educational organization) where internet connections are very slow. So we tried to get an ISP provider to connect all the branches using an MPLS ([Multiprotocol Label Switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprotocol_Label_Switching)) service but the price was too high. The MPLS is to restrict employees from accessing sites like Facebook, Youtube etc.

Another issue we had is we don't know who is accessing the PC at a given time to maintain log of activities. We also want to know which employee is using the PC at a given time. The only unique ID each employee has right now is their google apps for education ID (similar to google apps for business). Is there a way to link windows login to google apps? And if yes is there a software that lets you control user access to certain software? Any version of Windows is fine.